# Foursquare API: Syntax for using the time parameter in foursquare venues/explore

Tags: foursquare

I am trying to use the time parameter for the api : 
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=San Francisco&time=5 pm. I want to know what value to assign to 'time' parameter

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble as you have.

Maybe we can assign only `any` value to 'time' parameter.
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore